# Link to html pages in ionic creator pages

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I created a basic registration page using creator.ionic.io. I have downloaded , deployed in phone and came as expected.

I tried to explore the ionic generated html page and ended up with a question.

I could not find how index.html is rendering the register.html page i.e. where is the link inside div tag to register.html page.

There are 2 config.xml present in project and I am not sure which is considered to build.

One is inside android platform - I:\myprojects\silyap\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml

Other is at project name folder:
I:\myprojects\silyap\config.xml

Both config.xml has tag content src="index.html"

Can someone clarify it.

Below is the index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
  <div>
    <div>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-back">Back</ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

register.html page

```
<ion-view title="Register">
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" scroll="false" class="has-header has-footer">
        <form class="list">
            <ion-list>
                <label class="item item-input" name="Number">
                    <span class="input-label">Number</span>
                    <input type="tel" placeholder="">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input" name="Email">
                    <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="">
                </label>
            </ion-list>
            <button class="button  button-block ">Register</button>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: you should probably start by reading the documentation for ionic routing at http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/, then examine the contents of routes.js

Comment: this is not an answer but dont use creator if you are a newbie

Answer (score 0):

Awesome that you're using Ionic Creator. If you're unfamiliar with actual Ionic code, I recommend checking out http://AppCamp.io for a run through of how Angular + Ionic work together.